# Create dynamically linq query

Tags: c#, .net

I have an [EventLogEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlogentry.aspx) object:

```
EventLog aLog = new EventLog("Application");
IEnumerable<EventLogEntry> logentry=aLog.Entries.Cast<EventLogEntry>();
```

Now I'm trying create a dynamical linq query on `logentry` by its [InstanceId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlogentry.instanceid.aspx). I can run this:

```
int id=123;
IEnumerable<EventLogEntry> filteredByEventId = logentry.Where((x) => x.InstanceId == id);
```

but I'm trying to create linq terms at runtime. Something like this:

```
int id=123;
int id2=456;
IEnumerable<EventLogEntry> filteredByEventId = logentry.Where((x) => x.InstanceId == id || x.InstanceId == id2);
```

While I get that there is the "id2" too to add the the term at runtime.

**Update:**
my main goal is the user can ask for InstanceId range like
123, 456-789, 1000-1005
and i need to create the right query (dynamically) that will show him  all event with the following InstanceId 123 and between  456-789 (and 1000-1005)

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Are you always comparing ids?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the Linq *Contains* with a list/array?

```
var ids = new List<int>();
ids.Add(123);
ids.Add(456);
// etc...

IEnumerable<EventLogEntry> filteredByEventId = logentrey.Where((x) => ids.Contains(x.InstanceId));
```

**Edit**

To apply multiple ranges, you could use a collection of min/max tuples, and then use the Linq *All* method to filter by each range:

```
// setup ranges
var ranges = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
ranges.Add(new Tuple<int,int>(123,123));
ranges.Add(new Tuple<int,int>(456,789));
ranges.Add(new Tuple<int,int>(1000,1005));

// apply filter
var filteredByEventId = logentry.Where(x => 
    ranges.All(range => x >= range.Item1 && x <= range.Item2)
);
```

Comment: i can't get range(123-456) with this "Contains" statement.. so this can't help me..  thanks anyway

Comment: @user986474 I think a similar principle applies-- please see my update.